# Where to find implementation of preprocess_input in Keras / Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When you use a pretrained network such as VGG, ResNet, etc. it used to be that the they all had corresponding preprocess_input functions directly implemented in the functions that were being called/imported from the VGG / ResNet / etc. modules.

These are helpful to look at for ex. if you want to reverse the transformation.

Nowadays, the functions just look like this:

```
@keras_modules_injection
def decode_predictions(*args, **kwargs):
    return vgg16.decode_predictions(*args, **kwargs)
```

Which I got from here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/6d30ab70a4f116554aa610ec1c00a6bc5f1247f3/keras/applications/vgg16.py

If you search the Github repository for the string 'preprocess_input', there are no implementations to be found.

Where did they go?

Comment: What about [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet/preprocess_input)

Comment: I think you should look at [keras_applications](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/tree/master/keras_applications). For example in [resnet50](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/7f47d43c6ad697069cf53b0f13e384aef26014e3/keras_applications/resnet50.py#L22), the `preprocess_input` function is imported from [imagenet_utils](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/065c1ee7dbb9043c9fed571b086711d802d6bf31/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L152)

Comment: Thanks @akilat90, that's it. Didn't think it would be in an entirely different repository. Sucks that they bundled them all into one function.

Answer (score 0):

Providing answer for the details and reference for the Tensorflow 2.x implementations on for ImageNet data preprocessing & prediction decoding 
 under `tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils`.

Both [tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/imagenet_utils/preprocess_input) and [tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.decode_predictions()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/imagenet_utils/decode_predictions) has been moved under a single  class.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L97-L110) for the GitHub implementation on the same.